# Using rand() and srand() in C++

Tags: c++, class, ctime

I made a class with a function that returns a randomly generated `pair<int, int>` to represent a coordinate pair. At the beginning of the function I have `srand(time(NULL))` and I use `rand() % 50` to get the random number pair.

It works great... as long as I only have one object of that. If I have two different objects of that class and call the function for each object (by this I mean trying to generate two different random coordinates for two different objects of this class), it returns the exact same coordinate pair for each object.

In retrospect, I can understand why this happens -- because I'm getting the random number based off of the current time, right? But what method should I use to return a random pair EVERY TIME I call that class's function?

Comment: 1. Call `srand` **once** at the beginning of your program and **never** again. (unless you're purposely reproducing a seeded sequence). And 2. Stop using `srand()` and `rand()` altogether and start using the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library instead. Its the cat's whiskers.

Comment: See this good talk about [why rand can be considered harmful by STL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Answer (score 1):

> At the beginning of the function I have `srand(time(NULL))`

Call `srand()` *once* at the beginning of your program and never again.

PS: Consider using [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) instead of C-traditional functions.